为什么「五二〇运动」没有别称「五廿运动」？
这里的「五二〇运动」，是指1947年5月20日这一天爆发的学生运动。
这个问题是我在看到「五卅运动」后想到的，这个发生在1925年5月30日。这说明这个事件是以日期命名的，同时，它也被称为「五三〇事件」。在日常行文中，一般以「五卅运动」为主。
然而，精确检索「五廿运动」，结果只有零星几个，并且都指向「臺大學生自覺運動」（1960年代发生的）。这个也是以日期（5月20日）命名的。没有一条义项指向标题中的「五二〇运动」。这说明「五二〇运动」没有别称「五廿运动」。
「廿」和「卅」的构词方式、使用方式等基本一致，并且「廿」的使用频率较「卅」更高，如农历日期中，用「廿三」表示农历23日等。而因为农历所使用的阴阳历系统中，每月不超过30天，所以「卅」字在此无用武之地（当然，整十的时候，日期中的20日是被称为「二十」，30日被称为「三十」，并不是单字「廿」「卅」）。又如，对于如我一样的一（大？）部分共和国人，很多是通过比如历史课上的「五卅运动」初识「卅」字的而非相反，而「廿」字则在年龄很小的时候就可以在日历上看到。
既然「卅」字比「廿」字更冷清，那么为什么当初命名「五卅运动」时用了「卅」字，并作为主流命名；而命名「五二〇运动」时却未采用、哪怕是提及「五廿运动」「五廿事件」这些名称呢？
我认为这可能不只是一个遣词上的问题，甚至会涉及到历史文化背景、政治运作等多方面的考量，也有可能此事并非出于理性的原因。但是我还是对此很好奇，因此希望听到各位的高见。

我猜是受方言影响。
五卅运动发于上海，我推测上海方言习惯使用“卅”表达 30。我是金华人，金华方言在表达 30 就时习惯使用“卅”。上海方言和金华方言同属吴语，而且确实有大量的相同和相似之处（我能听懂上海话）。
五二零运动发于南京，南京方言与普通话差不多，所以表达 20 应该不用“廿”。
